# Configuring ImageResizer to run as an Azure virtual application

Tags: imageresizer

I am trying to configure ImageResizer to run as an Azure virtual application so that it will run in the same web role as our main MVC application but a separate worker process.  It appears that AzureReader2 isn't flexible enough to accomodate this.

An Azure virtual application adds an additional subfolder to the url and so does ImageResizer.

The following url results when using the Azure emulator is used and the Azure virtual application name is set to "ir" and the default subfolder of "azure" is used for the AzureReader2 plug-in:

```
http://127.0.0.2:81/ir/azure/datstat-resources-17/94fdf833-d457-4ed5-bce1-abf403381460.jpg?width=400
```

This example works just fine.  The problem comes when NO query string is specified and the request is redirected to use blob storage.  When I remove the query string the following url is produced:

```
http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/re/datstat-resources-17/94fdf833-d457-4ed5-bce1-abf403381460.jpg
```

I'm very confused as to how this url is formed.  What I want is for the "/re" subfolder portion to be removed from the url.

Here are my AzureReader2 web.config settings:

```
<add name="AzureReader2" connectionString="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" endpoint="http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/" />
```

Is there any way to fix or control the way this url is formed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug has been fixed in the latest development version, and will be included in the next release.

The blob redirect path is incorrect for any application not mounted at the domain root.

E-mail `support@imageresizing.net` to get a hotfix and claim your bug report reward.

Comment: Thank you for the fix Nathanael!  It worked great and made my day!